# Duplicate definition of column 'random_id' on entity 'Acme\ApiBundle\Entity\Client' in a field or discriminator column mapping

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, symfony, fosoauthserverbundle

I created client which extends FOSOAuthServerBundle. The code of this client is the following:

```
<?php 
namespace Acme\ApiBundle\Entity;
use FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\Client as BaseClient;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 /**
 * Class Client
 *
 * @package Acme\ApiBundle\Entity
 *
 * @ORM\Table("oauth2_clients")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Client extends BaseClient
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
    protected $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
   }
}
```

So, as I said, I extend the [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) which has $randomId (\friendsofsymfony\oauth-server-bundle\Entity\Client.php, line 28). Now I get an error:

> MappingException in MappingException.php line 565:
> Duplicate definition of column 'random_id' on entity 'Acme\ApiBundle\Entity\Client' in a field or discriminator column mapping.

Where did I a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used `FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\Client`, I used a class which extends another, target class (`FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\Client`). There were targeted variables, such as $RandomId which I found dublicate. So, according to my opinion, as `Acme\ApiBundle\Entity\Client` extends `FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Entity\Client` which extends `FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\Client`, we got variables twice instead of once. So I decided to extend `FOS\OAuthServerBundle\Model\Client` directly and it solves my issue. Can anyone explain why it is impossible to do code in a such way?